# C# Use a class that implements an interface without adding a reference to the assembly that defines the interface

Tags: c#

I have 3 assemblies written in C#, namely A.exe, B.dll, C.dll

- C.dll defines a public interface IfaceC.
- A.exe defines a public class ClassA : IfaceC
- B.dll uses ClassA but does not make explicit use of IfaceC

My question: is it possible to compile B **without** referencing C.dll ? I do not use it and I want to prevent a developer from using it (i.e. typing "IfaceC" in the B's code accidentally). However A.exe still needs it.

**EDIT**

Given my archi, A can reference C but not B, C cannot reference nor A neither B, B can reference A **but not (if possible) C**

Comment: Yes I tried. The compiler says I have to reference it. I was wondering if there is another way to do it

Comment: Make ClassA implement a seperate/new interface in A.exe which B.dll can reference, such that B doesn't know anything about concrete ClassA or the C.dll interface it implements...

Comment: @MattDavey: I think Matt is right on the money for this particular scenario (better than my own answer). Perhaps make it an answer?

Comment: What is original intent of this question ? Basically one approach is for A to still reference C, but just add extra protection so noone except allowed assemblies will be to load C. Can be made even as run-time check - A runs C.SetLicense("I'm authorized, please let me pass."); B does not perform that call and C will throw exception because of this.

Comment: I understand @coffee_machine's frustration here. An interface is supposed to decouple types, but client and consumer types must be tightly linked to make use of each other's interfaces. I would have thought that the Interface contract could be reduced to text matches, in the way a SQL query will work across tables with the same column names, but any reference to classes would need to go back to a strict type match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You need to have a reference to any assemblies containing base types or interfaces implemented by any types you use.

Comment: If this is true, that would be really bad for my plugin architecture. It would mean that I have to update every plugin for having added an implementation of an interface that no plugin uses :(

Comment: @coffee_machine: have you missed MattDavey's comment? It is both simple and effective. I would even consider the implementing classes an implementation  detail that should never be exposed in a plugin interface.

Comment: Yup, I agree with that suggestion. If you don't want a client to know some details of a type, don't expose that type if you can help it.

Answer (score 0):

The only *other way* evades your question and involves `Duck Typing`.

C#'s `dynamic` *type* keyword is very handy in this respect. It has the drawback of no longer having static type checking during compilation.

In effect, using dynamic you can pass in any object of (unknown) type, much like you pass `object` instances. The compiler let's you use the object by calling methods/properties and whatnot, as if the type was known.

Code will be emitted that looks up the relevant properties at runtime. This means that at runtime the metadata will be consulted (and the common assembly is still being loaded). The net gain is ***only*** that the 'third' assembly is not referenced, and need not be present at compilation or program loading time.

---

- http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/19/why-duck-typing-matters-to-c-developers.aspx
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing

Comment: Can you explain how that would help in this case?

Comment: I suspect `dynamic` won't solve the problem. You still need to assign the dynamic variable to an object of ClassA - and you can't create it without referencing C.dll

Comment: The point is that you might not need to assign it to a ClassA variable. Iff that is the case, then, of course, all bets are off. I still think MattDavey has contributed the best idea, but I can hardly go and take credit for that, now can I?

Comment: thanks @sehe :) Jon's answer of "no" is technically correct for the question *"is it possible to compile B without referencing C.dll?"*

Comment: @MattDavey: I know. I'm not saying otherwise. I think you _contributed the best idea_ in terms of real life problem solving potential. Of course having the facts is a first requirement, as always