# assembly reference in multi layer C# project

Tags: unity-game-engine, multi-layer

My multi layer project has Datalayer, services, panel. dataLayer referenced to services, and services referenced to panel. i have an interface in datalayer, some thing like

```
public interface IJournalEntity
{
   ...
}
```

my services has a class that inherited from IJournalEntity,

```
public class OfflinePaymentService : IOfflinePaymentService, IJournalEntity
{
...                
}
```

when i compile panel layer, unity config raise an error to add reference to data layer, how could i fix withoud referenced that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot fix without referenced that. The type is unknown to your project if you don't reference it.

Some similar questions:

1. [Access interface methods without referring the class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498464/access-interface-methods-without-referring-the-class)
2. [C# Use a class that implements an interface without adding a reference to the assembly that defines the interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646769/c-sharp-use-a-class-that-implements-an-interface-without-adding-a-reference-to-t)

If your datalayer is defined in a separate dll, you need to put that in `Assets/Plugins/`. This applied to Unity3D 4.x.
On Unity3D 5.x, just put the dll in `Assets` will work.

- [Documentation for plugins](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html)
- [Documentation for plugins on Unity3D 5.x](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UpgradeGuide5-Plugins.html)